# Make header and div height of viewport

Tags: javascript, html, css

having a bit a trouble achieving something.  I want a page which has a header with its navigation, and then I want the rest of the page to be an image which fills out the viewport.

At the moment I have something like this

```
<header id="header" class="header-default">
   ...nav items
</header>

<div id="contents"></div>
```

In my CSS I then do

```
#header.header-default{
    height: 100px;
    padding-top:10px;
    padding-bottom:10px;
}

#contents{
    background: url('images/home.jpg') no-repeat center center fixed;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

Then lastly I have some javascript to set the height of contents.

```
jQuery(function() {
    setHeight();

    jQuery(window).resize(function() {
        setHeight();
    });
});

function setHeight() {
    windowHeight = jQuery(window).innerHeight()-120;
    jQuery('.home #contents').css('min-height', windowHeight);
};
```

Now it kind of works, it fits the viewport as it should do.  However, the image is of a person, and it cuts the top of their forehead off.  Is there any way to make the image display perfectly?  If doing the viewport size is not an option due to the ratio (which I think is happening) then I dont mind displaying it normally.

Thanks

Comment: Have you attempted modifying the background position from `center center` to `top center`?

Comment: still cuts off the top

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The combination of `background-size: cover` and `background-attachment: fixed` is the cause of the problem. Except for the `background-attachment: fixed` can cause degraded performance with animations, as the background is repainted all the time. To get the required result, use a ::before pseudo-element with `position: fixed` - [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ry5dqeu9/5/).

btw - in this way you can also drop the height changing script, as the background is always 100% available height;

```
body::before {
    display: block;
    position: fixed;
    top: 120px; /** so it will be under the header **/
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    background: url('http://blog.homerealestate.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/04/Person.Ashley.jpg') no-repeat;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    content:'';
}

#contents {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 10; /** above the background **/
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Feels like a familiar issue. I think it is indeed a mismatch of ratios (image vs viewport/containing element).

If memory serves, you can tweak with the padding to get to what you want to display.

Check out Nicholas Gallagher's [Flexible CSS Cover Images demo](http://nicolasgallagher.com/flexible-css-cover-images/)

The key bit there is:

> Changing that padding value will change the aspect ratio. For example, padding of 25% results in an aspect ratio of 4:1, padding of 33.333% results in an aspect ratio of 3:1, etc.

Also, a caveat to keep in mind (CSS hack, after all):

> The problem with using this aspect ratio hack is that if the element has a max-height declared, it will not be respected. To get around this, the hack can be applied to a pseudo-element instead.